# How to do angularjs ng-view routing in asp.net

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have mvc project in asp.net.

This is my home page:
Home.cshtml

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    ... 
</head>
<body>
     <div ng-view style="height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my angular rout config:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','$provide',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/Home', {
            templateUrl: 'FirstPage/ShowFirstPage',
        })
        .when('/Book', {
            templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
        });


      $provide.decorator('$templateRequest', function ($delegate) {
          var mySilentProvider = function (tpl, ignoreRequestError) {
              return $delegate(tpl, true);
          }
          return mySilentProvider;
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
      });
  }])
```

And this is rout config of asp.net:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "Home",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowHomePage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

The routing (ng-view) not working.
I need to create one page application with angularjs and asp.net.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** There is conflict between Angular route and MVC route, you have defined "Home" in MVC as well as Angular Route, you should catch all the default url on the MVC to avoid the conflict like following.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Catching of url means, MVC will not try to resolve the URL anymore for the default route. Otherwise MVC will try to find the view instead of Angular JS

**2-** You want your Home view to be loaded from the client side, so  remove following route as it has been defined as an Angular route.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "Home",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowHomePage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**3-** You also have defined your action as Index in the default MVC route, change it to Home or move your Home.chtml code to Index.cstml

**4-** Finally in the Angular route add the default route also

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
```

Comment: *routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ShowHomePage", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );  * It create endless loop

Comment: url: "{*catchall}" ** > this line create the loop. I removed the Home rout that you told me and no change. It still in loop. if I change url: "{*catchall}" to url: "Home" it load the main page but not load the ng-view page

Comment: did you followed all the steps?

Comment: You need to clearly understand the routing , you can check this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1033076/Integrating-AngularJS-with-ASP-NET-MVC